# JavaScript works when calling with Node but only particularly when calling from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, raspberry-pi

My externaljsfile.JS looks like this:

```
"use strict";

const fsLibrary  = require('fs');

function save_installform() {
  alert("Step1");
  fsLibrary.writeFile('/home/pi/newfile.txt', "Hello world.", (error) => {
    alert("Error");
  });
  alert("Written");
};
```

When calling it with `node externaljsfile.js` on my raspberry pi it works and creates the text file.

But when including it with `src` in my HTML server and then calling the function `save_installform()` with a button, there it only shows "Step 1" as alert like coded and breaks after. No "Error" or "Written" alert and no file.

Is this a permission problem or something like that?

Comment: this code is nodejs not javascript

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-node-js-and-javascript/#:~:text=Javascript%20is%20a%20programming%20language,is%20a%20Javascript%20runtime%20environment.&text=Javascript%20can%20only%20be%20run,be%20run%20outside%20the%20browser.

Comment: `require` doesn't exist in browser javascript

Comment: There is likely an error showing up in your browser's console. Press F12 or otherwise bring up your browser's Developer Tools and see what errors are showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fs is a library for nodejs, you cannot use it on client-side. You can lookup for some methods to do so on client, like this: [How to create a file in memory for user to download, but not through server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server)

Comment: Is there a way of creating a file with javascript the same way the shown nodejs-code does?

Comment: @Tim no. Client side js can't have access to file system

Comment: @Tim I used this https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

Comment: @Viet This only provides to txt to the client, not the server